# Overfull \vbox with mdframed box in environments

Tags: environments, mdframed, overfull

I'm getting a lot of "Overfull \vbox" errors when using an mdframed box in my custom theorem and proof environments. I have reduced the problem to the minimum example below. I use the equations to push down the environment so that supposedly they are split between two pages.

What is the problem, and how do I solve these overfull \vbox warnings?

[image: Lots of overfull vbox errors]

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newmdenv{proofbox}
\newmdenv{theorembox}

\newtheorem{theorem_}[equation]{Theorem}

\newenvironment{theorem}
{ 
  \begin{theorembox}
  \begin{theorem_}
}
{
  \end{theorem_}
  \end{theorembox}
}

\newenvironment{fproof}[1][]
{
  \begin{proofbox}
  #1
}
{
  \end{proofbox}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{theorem}
A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{fproof}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{fproof}

\end{document}
```

Here's how the pdf looks:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `mdframed`: it has been abandoned because in the meantime the more powerful `tcolorbox` package appeared.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Theorem}
\NewEnvironmentCopy{fproof}{proof}
\tcolorboxenvironment{theorem}{sharp corners,colback=white,boxrule=0.4pt}
\tcolorboxenvironment{fproof}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{theorem}
A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{fproof}
We see that
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2 \\
E & = mc^2.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
so we finished our proof.
\end{fproof}

\end{document}
```

Customize your `proof` box as to your liking.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was able to simplify a lot of my environment code by replacing mdframed with tcolorbox and following your example here.